# AddMediaObject and AddMediaObject2 compiler error

Tags: vba, audio, video, powerpoint

ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddMediaObject2(audioFileName, msoFalse, msoTrue, 50, 50, 50, 50) presents an error every single time, regardless of it having the full string including Filename:=, etc.  It also will not work with AddMediaObject either.

This:
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddMediaObject2 audioFileName, msoFalse, msoTrue, 50, 50, 50, 50

does not throw a compiler error, but also does not work.  I am incredibly confused, as this has been frustrating me for 3 days straight.  I have searched and tried every format anyone has typed for this type of code, and I cannot for the life of me get it to work.

It does not work for audio OR video.  Pictures work just fine with AddPicture, but it must be in a

ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddPicture Filename:=picFileName, LinkToFile:=msoFalse, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=50, Top:=50, Width:=50, Height:=50

type format, and will NOT work with ( or ) surrounding the filename to height.

Also, the compiler error tells me to add an equal sign and a string... but at the END of the format with brackets.  I have no idea what is going on.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

.Add and many other methods can act as statements or functions.

ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddMediaObject2(audioFileName, msoFalse, ... etc etc (ie with the Parens after AddMediaObject2) is a function that will return a reference to the newly added media object so you need to do

```
Set SomeObject = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddMediaObject2(audioFileName, msoFalse,
```

instead.  Or leave out the the parens if you're not going to do anything with the returned object reference.

Your second syntax (w/o the parens) works here as long as I supply the full path to a valid media file, one that PPT is able to import on its own manually.

What error do you get when you run the code?

Comment: So, this code:
   


`Sub addaudio()
Set audio1 = ActivePresentation.Slides(p).Shapes.AddMediaObject(FileName:=ActivePresentation.Path & "\audio\audio" & p & ".wav", Left:=5, Top:=5, Width:=1, Height:=1)
End Sub`   


   
Works just fine... but if I change it to AddMediaObject2, and add the LinkToFile, and SaveWithDocument, it no longer works.

Comment: What version of PPT are you using this in?  Do you see AddMediaObject2 listed in the object browser?  It's not supported in earlier versions of PPT (I'm not sure exactly when it was introduced, though).  If it's not in the object browser, it's not supported in your version, though.

Comment: Must be low on sleep.  I was trying to solve it alongside a filedialog and AddMediaObject2.  Got it working this weekend.  Thanks a lot for the help!  Well on my way to finishing this project.